# Can a mprotect() call lead to priority inheritance in Linux scheduling?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

Is it possible, that a call of `mprotect()` in Linux can lead to priority inheritance?

When analyzing an `ftrace` file, I see a call of `mprotect()` by Task 1 followed by a priority inheritance. Task 2 gets priority of Task 1 and is scheduled. After some time Task 2 gets back its original priority and Task 1 gets active again. `mprotect()` immediately returns with exit code 0 (successful).

It looks like Task 1 and 2 are using a common resource. But how is `mprotect()` involved here?